# Keyboard shortcut to toggle tabs in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I know how to toggle tabs, to switch between files, in eclipse. But, how do I toggle tabs like ***Manifest, Application, Permissions, Instrumentation and AndroidManifest.xml***, which are inside the **AndrdoidManifest file of my project**, using a keyboard shortcut. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt + PgUp for next tab
Alt + PgDown for previous tab

Comment: That's right. You can also do it using ALT+SUPER_KEY+F7. But, the one you suggested is more convenient. Thanks.